# React Native how to scroll FlatList down?

Tags: react-native, error-handling, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm trying to make a chat app with React Native.
My Chat Screen has a `FlatList` where all messages passed as data.

To Scroll the `FlatList` I'm trying to use ref like this:

```
const scrollRef = useRef<FlatList<MessageType[]>>(null);

<FlatList ref={scrollRef} onContentSizeChange={() => scrollRef.current?.scrollToEnd()} style={{ flex: 1 }} data={chatMessages} renderItem={({ item }) => <MessageBox key={item._id} data={item} />} removeClippedSubviews={false} />
```

But each time I call `scrollRef.current?.scrollToEnd();` I'm getting an error:

**Tried to get frame for out-of-range index -1**

Does anybody know what this error mean and how can scroll `FlatList` to the bottom each time when new message appear?

*PS:* ***FlatList is not empty.***

Comment: do u see this error when you send a new chat or when chat screen loads?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone will stumble over the same problem, what helped me is:

1. Reverse FlatList
2. Reverse messages array.

In my case I also required to reverse messages array each time I updated screen with new message

The code:

```
<FlatList inverted style={{ flex: 1 }} data={chatMessages.reverse()} renderItem={({ item }) => <MessageBox key={item._id} data={item} />} removeClippedSubviews={false} />
```

Pay attention in word **inverted** and data={**chatMessages.reverse()**}

Also when updating the screen:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receiveMessage", (data) => {
        setChatMessages([...chatMessages.reverse(), data.msg]);
    });
}, [socket, chatMessages])
```